# How to find the minimum score of each use from a list of MongoDB documents using Java 8 stream

Tags: mongodb, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Assuming I have the following MongoDB documents collected in a list,

```
List<Document> all

{ "student_id" : 0, "score" : 14.8504 }
{ "student_id" : 0, "score" : 63.98403 }
{ "student_id" : 1, "score" : 21.33265 }
{ "student_id" : 1, "score" : 44.31668 }
{ "student_id" : 2, "score" : 60.9750 }
{ "student_id" : 2, "score" : 97.75888 }
{ "student_id" : 3, "score" : 50.81575 }
```

I would like to extract the minimum score of each user into a map using Java 8 stream with lambda expressions. The desired result would be

```
{0=14.8504, 1=21.33265, 2=60.9750, 3=50.81575}
```

The following works, however, it seems a bit too complicated.  Is there a simpler method?

```
Map<Integer, Double> result = all.stream().
    flatMap(d -> Collections.singletonMap(d.getInteger("student_id"), 
        d.getDouble("score")).entrySet().stream()).
    collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Math::min));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not simply `all.stream().collect(toMap(d -> d.getInteger("student_id"), d -> d.getDouble("score"), Math::min);`?

Comment: `flatMap(d -> singletonMap(…).entrySet().stream())` is really baroque for getting a single `Map.Entry`. A `map(d -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(…))` would do the same. But why creating an `Entry` to extract it’s two values right afterwards? As [assylias asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143179/how-to-find-the-minimum-score-of-each-use-from-a-list-of-mongodb-documents-using#comment52176901_32143179), why not just extract the two values right in the `toMap` collector…

Comment: @assylias and Holger, you're right. I wasn't thinking straight.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupingBy in the Collectors utility class was designed specifically for this task, so you should do something like this

```
Map<Integer, Double> maxScoreByStudentId = this.documents.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Document::getStudentId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Document::getScore)), d -> d.get().getScore())));
```

1. groupingBy constructs a Map using Document::getStudentId as key.
2. collectingAndThen does two things:

   2.1 Computes the document with the min score for each group with minBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Document::getScore)). Note that minBy returns an Optional

   2.2 Then extracts the score with the lambda d -> d.get().getScore(). As minBy return an Optional it is necessary to extract its value with d.get